# Awking multiple times in a shell script file

Tags: memory, awk, size, cluster-computing, slurm

I am sending a batch file to a slurm cluster that awks fields of the same infile and appends to an output. First few lines work but then suddenly it dies. It dies before echoing the second time. It would be nice if someone would debug or show me a better script but I would like to know why (or if) a bash file would crash when it is doing the same job over and over again.

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH -A b2014091
#SBATCH -p core
#SBATCH -n 1
#SBATCH -t 23:00:00
#SBATCH -J sbatch

#input was MK...vcf

input=$1

output=$(grep -v '^#' ${input} | awk '(substr($12,1,3)=="1/1") && (substr($15,1,3)=="1/1") {print $0}')
echo "$output\n" >> /proj/b2014091/nobackup/potHomoF1.txt
output=$(grep -v '^#' ${input} | awk '(substr($12,1,3)=="0/0") && (substr($15,1,3)=="0/0") {print $0}')
echo "$output\n" >> /proj/b2014091/nobackup/potHomoF1.txt
output=$(grep -v '^#' ${input} | awk '(substr($12,1,3)=="1/1") && (substr($15,1,3)=="./.") {print $0}')
echo "$output\n" >> /proj/b2014091/nobackup/potHomoF1.txt
output=$(grep -v '^#' ${input} | awk '(substr($12,1,3)=="./.") && (substr($15,1,3)=="1/1") {print $0}')
echo "$output\n" >> /proj/b2014091/nobackup/potHomoF1.txt
output=$(grep -v '^#' ${input} | awk '(substr($12,1,3)=="0/0") && (substr($15,1,3)=="./.") {print $0}')
echo "$output\n" >> /proj/b2014091/nobackup/potHomoF1.txt
output=$(grep -v '^#' ${input} | awk '(substr($12,1,3)=="./.") && (substr($15,1,3)=="0/0") {print $0}')
echo "$output\n" >> /proj/b2014091/nobackup/potHomoF1.txt
```

Error message:

slurmstepd: get_exit_code task 0 died by signal

Example of field 12-15:

```
1/1:0,38:38:99:1149,114,0       1/1:0,39:39:99:1161,117,0       1/1:0,46:46:99:1383,138,0       0/1:21,18:39:99:413,0,524
```

Comment: What is the error message when it fails ?

Comment: Also can you give an example of the string you are taking substrs from ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can change all of this:

```
input=$1

output=$(grep -v '^#' ${input} | awk '(substr($12,1,3)=="1/1") && (substr($15,1,3)=="1/1") {print $0}')
echo "$output\n" >> /proj/b2014091/nobackup/potHomoF1.txt
output=$(grep -v '^#' ${input} | awk '(substr($12,1,3)=="0/0") && (substr($15,1,3)=="0/0") {print $0}')
echo "$output\n" >> /proj/b2014091/nobackup/potHomoF1.txt
output=$(grep -v '^#' ${input} | awk '(substr($12,1,3)=="1/1") && (substr($15,1,3)=="./.") {print $0}')
echo "$output\n" >> /proj/b2014091/nobackup/potHomoF1.txt
output=$(grep -v '^#' ${input} | awk '(substr($12,1,3)=="./.") && (substr($15,1,3)=="1/1") {print $0}')
echo "$output\n" >> /proj/b2014091/nobackup/potHomoF1.txt
output=$(grep -v '^#' ${input} | awk '(substr($12,1,3)=="0/0") && (substr($15,1,3)=="./.") {print $0}')
echo "$output\n" >> /proj/b2014091/nobackup/potHomoF1.txt
output=$(grep -v '^#' ${input} | awk '(substr($12,1,3)=="./.") && (substr($15,1,3)=="0/0") {print $0}')
echo "$output\n" >> /proj/b2014091/nobackup/potHomoF1.txt
```

To this?

```
awk '!/^#/ && substr($12,1,3)~/[01.]\/[01.]/ && substr($15,1,3)~/[01.]\/[01.]/' <<< $1 > /proj/b2014091/nobackup/potHomoF1.txt
```

Try both of this:

```
awk '{a=substr($12,1,3);b=substr($15,1,3)} !/^#/ && ((a=="1/1" && b=="1/1") || (a=="0/0" && b=="0/0") || (a=="1/1" && b=="./.") || (a=="./." && b=="1/1") || (a=="0/0" && b=="./.") || (a=="./." && b=="0/0"))' $1 > /proj/b2014091/nobackup/potHomoF1.txt
```

or

```
input=$1
awk '{a=substr($12,1,3);b=substr($15,1,3)} !/^#/ && ((a=="1/1" && b=="1/1") || (a=="0/0" && b=="0/0") || (a=="1/1" && b=="./.") || (a=="./." && b=="1/1") || (a=="0/0" && b=="./.") || (a=="./." && b=="0/0"))' ${input} > /proj/b2014091/nobackup/potHomoF1.txt
```

Comment: Won't this include "0/1" which is one of the strings I am avoiding?

Comment: Maybe something like `/\([01.]\)\/(\1)/`

Comment: Yes it will.  I may be that you have to split it up, but you still could do all in one `awk`  Try this `awk '!/^#/ && substr($12,1,3)~/(1\/1)|(0\/0)|(\.\/\.)/ && substr($15,1,3)~/(1\/1)|(0\/0)|(\.\/\.)/'`

Comment: Nothing happend, nothing at all. Finished after one minute with an empty output and without an error message.

Comment: And I do not want $12=="1/1" && $15=="0/0" as I think this would give me.

Comment: Then you need split it up like I sad above.  `awk '{a=substr($12,1,3);b=substr($15,1,3)} !/^#/ && ((a=="1/1" && b=="1/1") || (a=="0/0" && b=="0/0") || (a=="1/1" && b=="./.") || (a=="./." && b=="1/1") || (a=="0/0" && b=="./.") || (a=="./." && b=="0/0"))'`

Comment: when `infile=$1` and then input to awk is ${infile} it worked. Paste it to your answer to get acceptance. I had tried similar things without success. Why didn't my script work in the first place?

Comment: Thanks for accepting it.  I have updated it some,  try both and see what works.